# Consuming messages from apache kafka in avro format

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, java-8, spring-kafka

I want to consume messages from my Kafka broker using a spring boot configured consumer using the spring-Kafka library, the source is a JDBC connector which is responsible for pulling messages from a MySQL database and these messages need to be consumed

Below I am attaching my application.yml file

```
server:
  port: 9000
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      group-id: group_id
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    producer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      value-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

Consumer -

```
  @KafkaListener(topics = "Sample-Topic", groupId = "group_id")
    public void consume(String message) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
```

Messages in topics are stored in Avro format as I am using JDBC connector.

Instead of the JSON, I am getting encrypted output and some of the output messages are only plain strings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the avro deserializer instead of `StringDeserializer`.